# VS2010 on XP SP3 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-xp

We are soon to get VS2010 and according to the link below, Microsoft do not support VS2010 on XP x64.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/professional/system-requirements

**Does anyone have XP 64bit running VS2010?**

I am not interested in 64bit version of VS (I am wanting to install a 32bit version of VS2010 professional on a 64 bit XP machine).

I am aware that XP will require SP3.

**Any warnings? Horror stories? Advice?**

Comment: Upgrade to Windows 7. Seriously, if your hardware is too old to be running Windows 7, then it's too old to be running VS2010.

Comment: @codeka: I wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: For the sake of clarity: *Windows XP x64* and *Windows XP 64-Bit* are two completely different products. The former runs on x64 processors, the latter on Itanium processors. I doubt that anyone really cares much about an Itanium version of XP anymore, but it's still good to be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to feedback on my experiences to date - works fine not ever a single problem (xp 64 bit, 8Gb RAM, 2.66Ghz duo).  Finally moved to Windows 7!!

Answer (score 2):

I just recently found out that one error in installing VS2010 in Windows 64-bit is the .net 4.0 it tries to locate WindowsCodecs.dll from System32 forlder, and when i tried to investigate I found out that the file is located in the Windows64 dit folder, so I copy the file in to the System32 folder and then tried installing VS2010 again and it went smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

It installed fine for me, but a couple days later I'm noticing some .Net programs are no longer working (among other random apps I could find no correlation in). After messing around with it a bunch, I've determined the problem to be VS 2010. Also, every time I try to run these applications a VS 2010 debugger pops up, which is too great a co-incidence to not be related. I've uninstalled everything on my PC (freshly formatted WIN-XP 64-Bit edition here that only had 10-15 apps installed), all the way back to what it was when it was after I installed XP. I've tried reinstalling VS2010 and still no avail, I'm still getting errors when trying to open certain applications. And I've even got the BSOD from merely opening VS2010. From what I've dealt with so far, I would seriously advise against you trying this. I'm going to try and further mess with mine but if I had to go back and start again there's no way I would do this again. Waaay to much of a headache (why do the .NET frameworks take so long to install/remove!?)..

EDIT:
In case somebody was wondering, these are the apps that stopped working for me post VS 2010 installation: Stardock Fences, Opera Web Browser 11.50, Teracopy, WinRAR
, and "Everything Search" (which would launch, but always crashed about 15+ minutes after boot)

Comment: Just to feedback - I finally got VS2010 installed on my XP SP3 machine and no problems whatsoever (64 bit machine).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't screw around with XP x64.  Bite the bullet and upgrade to Win 7 x64.

Quite frankly, VS2010 hasn't been out long enough for anyone to find most of the issues that you might face.  I wouldn't want to find myself in a situation where it installed, worked for simple things, then completely held up our development process because of some hidden issue we didn't find until too late.

Comment: I agree whole heartedly.  I have Win 7 at home with VS2010 and loving it to bits.  However, larger organisations are a bit more cautious around new technology and so may take time to get Win 7 installed.  It goes against my very grain :)